# Styled components + Typescript: How do I type the css helper function?

Tags: typescript, styled-components

I have a component that has a bunch of unique styles depending on the variant prop:

```
interface CommonStyleProps {
  filled_icon: boolean;
}
const primaryStyles = css<CommonStyleProps>`...`
const ghostStyles = css<CommonStyleProps>`...`

const calculateColors = (
  variant: BUTTON_VARIANTS
) => {
  switch (variant) {
    case BUTTON_VARIANTS.GHOST:
      return ghostStyles;
    case BUTTON_VARIANTS.PRIMARY:
    default:
      return primaryStyles;
  }
};

interface ContainerProps {
  variant: BUTTON_VARIANTS;
}

const Container = styled.button<ContainerProps>`
  ${({ variant }) => calculateColors(variant)}.  // <---------- Typescript complains here
`;
```

However, Typescript is complaining that `calculateColors` has the wrong return type.

[image]

When I update the return type to this, it works:

```
import styled, {
  css,
  keyframes,
  FlattenInterpolation,
  ThemedStyledProps,
} from 'styled-components';

...

const calculateColors = (
  variant: BUTTON_VARIANTS
): FlattenInterpolation<ThemedStyledProps<any, any>> => {
  ...
};
```

Is there a better way to define the return type of `css` without using `any`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

Had to remove CommonStylesProps and use ContainerProps + DefaultTheme

```
const calculateColors = (
  variant: BUTTON_VARIANTS
): FlattenInterpolation<ThemedStyledProps<ContainerProps, DefaultTheme>> => {
  switch (variant) {
    case BUTTON_VARIANTS.SECONDARY:
      return secondaryStyles;
    case BUTTON_VARIANTS.INTERACTIVE:
      return interactiveStyles;
    case BUTTON_VARIANTS.GHOST:
      return ghostStyles;
    case BUTTON_VARIANTS.PRIMARY:
    default:
      return primaryStyles;
  }
};
```